# How to prove that antivirus is capble of detecting and removing malware?

Tags: malware, antivirus

How can we check if any antivirus is capable of detecting, removing and protecting from the malware? Can it be verified by checking the configuration of the antivirus or by just doing a live scan? If I need to show the evidence that any particular antivirus is working, how can it be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "the malware"? Do you have any specific malware in mind? Most anti virus vendors have a database of known malware. You can find for example [McAfee's database here](https://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/malware/latest.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The [EICAR test file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file) is made just for this purpose. Every signature based malware scanner should detect this file. Everything else just depends on trust.

Answer (score 0):

To check anti virus is capable to detect

Use EICAR test file

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file

you can download it from https://www.ikarussecurity.com/support/virus-info/test-viruses/

or

simply copy and paste the following string in text file and scan with antivirus

```
X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*
```

check this post also for Malware database

[Where to download thousands of virus samples for AV testing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127606/where-to-download-thousands-of-virus-samples-for-av-testing)

In order to detect latest virus and malware you need to update the Anti Virus database regularly

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, that this answers the OP's question.

Comment: he just want to know whether his anti virus is capable of detecting and removing this what i do to check my AV

Comment: TBH that just proves that the EICAR file ist detected and gets deleted. this just proves that the Software is generally able to detect files and delete them - It does not prove that the software is able to delete malware that in any way tries to evade the deletion process (which imho is not proofable)